# Proving the order of complexity proofs

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Show that if f(n) is Ω(n∗g(n)), then f(n) is not O(g(n).

Assume f(n) is Ω(n ∗ g(n)) and f(n) is O(g(n)). Want to show a contradiction. The approach is to find a value of n that violates the definitions.
Proof: f(n) is Ω(n ∗ g(n)) implies there exists positive values C and k such that n > k implies f(n) ≥ C ∗ n ∗ g(n). f(n) is O(g(n)) implies there exists positive values C′ and k′ such that n > k′ implies f(n) ≤ C ∗ g(n).

Comment: What do you consider Omega and Big O to mean? Sometimes it's only lower bound, sometimes upper bound, sometimes both (especially when used colloquially). Either way, these represent limits as n approaches infinity, so it should be relatively easy to prove from the definition of a limit, that's my tip.

Comment: Omega means lower bound and Big O means upper bound.

Comment: @Maurycyt Omega and Big O notations have a mathematical definition so they don't have different meanings according how do you use them.

Comment: Yeah I looked those up. That's why added "especially when used colloquially", because I am currently a student and I lead algorithmics workshops for high school students, and neither me nor my peers ever pay attention to which bound is which, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following: Omega signifies the lower bound complexity and Big Oh signifies the upper bound complexity, this problem is solved using the definition of the two.

If f(n) is Omega(n*g(n)) then this means (from definition) that there exists an n<sub>0</sub> and an M<sub>0</sub>, such that for all n > n<sub>0</sub>, f(n) > M<sub>0</sub> * n * g(n).

If f(n) is O(g(n)) then this means (from definition), that there exists an n<sub>1</sub> and an M<sub>1</sub>, such that for all n > n<sub>1</sub>, f(n) < M<sub>1</sub> * g(n).

Let n<sub>2</sub> = max(n<sub>0</sub>, n<sub>1</sub>), then the for all n > n<sub>2</sub>, M<sub>1</sub> * g(n) > f(n) > M<sub>0</sub> * n * g(n).

We will now focus on the two complexities, without the function. We have M<sub>1</sub> * g(n) > M<sub>0</sub> * n * g(n), thus M<sub>1</sub> > M<sub>0</sub> * n, thus n < M<sub>1</sub>/M<sub>0</sub>.

Now, no matter what values M<sub>1</sub> and M<sub>0</sub> take, n < M<sub>1</sub>/M<sub>0</sub> is not true for all n > n<sub>2</sub>, which is necessary if we assume both complexities to be correct.

Thus, we arrive at a contradiction, so both complexities cannot be true at once.

Good luck in your studies.

Comment: nothing, really. It's just the larger of n_0 and n_1. Notice, that if something is satisfied for n > n_1, then it is satisfied for n > n_2. Similarly, if a condition is satisfied for n > n_0, then it is satisfied for n > n_2. I introduced n_2 to make sure the proof doesn't get too messy with ifs.